# how to convert mongodb db.currentOp() into json

Tags: mongodb

I want to create an interface for all running processes in Mongodb

How can I convert mongodb db.currentOp() output into json so that I can access that

The output currently is a BSON string and I cannot use any libraries that use json ... which would become convenient to develop an interface

Comment: What do you mean? `db.currentOp()` returns a JSON (or BSON being more accurate), what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem you are referring to is results returned in a MongoDB shell environment which use JavaScript helper syntax like `ISODate()` that is not compatible with JSON.

If so, the solution is to convert shell output into [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) which has JSON-compatible representations of all [BSON data types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-types/).

For example, using `mongosh`:

```
test> dt = new Date()
ISODate("2022-05-06T10:51:23.454Z")

test> EJSON.stringify(dt)
{"$date":"2022-05-06T10:51:23.454Z"}
```

If you want to convert `db.currentOp()` output into Extended JSON for use with standard libraries:

> mongosh --eval "EJSON.stringify(db.currentOp())" --quiet

The `--quiet` option suppresses startup messages (for example, version info or startup warnings) so output should only include results of the `--eval` call.

Comment: ok that works ... but only on mongo5x

Comment: My example was using `mongosh` (aka [The New MongoDB Shell](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/)) which supports MongoDB 4.0 or newer.